# -20 db/decade Gain Slope requirement for Stability?

Tags: power-supply, compensation, pole-compensation

I have been learning `Analog Filter` designing. I started with `Loop Compensation` in power supply. I came across a [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva503a/slva503a.pdf). It states that:

> The requirement for stability is typically met if the overall gain crosses 0 dB with a slope of –20 dB/Decade.

I have read so far for stability, there should be enough phase and gain margin and poles and zeros should be located at the left-hand size of the `s-plane`.

But I am not able to understand the requirement at Gain Slope when gain crosses 0 dB. Can someone explain this to me with some graphical representation?

Comment: That single slope statement is a bit simplistic; can you tell us where you found it?

Comment: I have attached the link in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that the stability criterion under these conditions (-20db slope at unity gain) is met - that means: fulfilled.

However, two important remarks:

- In your quote, the "overall gain" is mentioned. This sounds misleading to me. To be correct, this stability criterion applies to the LOOP GAIN of a circuit with feedback only (that means: loop not closed).
- The mentioned condition ensures a phase margin of app. 90 deg - which certainly fulfills the criterion. However, even with a phase margin of only 10 deg the circuit (after closing the loop) will be stable. But in many cases this margin is not sufficient (too much ringing in the step response). But it is "stable" from the system theory point of view. For many sysytems a margin of app. 60 deg is desired which gives a "good" step response with a small overshoot only.

(Further explanation: In most cases a gain drop with 20dB/dec is connected witha phase shift of app. -90 deg. Hence, we have a reserve of additional 90 deg until the "critical" value of -180deg).